# Why does the storyboard representation of my WKWebView look different to what runs on the simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, constraints, xcode-storyboard

How I can make my `WKWebView` match the safe area?

The safe area is the area where I can safely show content without bungle the status bar at the top or similar.

I thought I can just make my `WKWebView` a child of the Safe Area, but this is not possible.

I selected my Web View and then clicked on the constraints and selected safe area everywhere. But if I select "Web View" at the left, then it shows that it is way bigger than the safe area:

[image]

It looks like it does not even Mather how I position the webview if there is a constraint on it, e.g. I positioned it like this:

[image]

...but if I simulate it, then it still looks perfect.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you got some code on how you currently have your layout and constraints? Have you checked other similar links?

Comment: Code? I thought I can do this without code just by interacting with Xcode?

Comment: Since you shared a picture of the Storyboard, I am assuming you mean Storyboard and not Xcode - Xcode = an IDE, Storyboard = the picture you shared where you can drag and drop view elements. Best advice - lookup "How to set constraints in storyboard" - that will lead you to the solution you are after :-)

Comment: But what is wrong with my constraints? Why is it showing that the webview is much bigger than the safe area? If I build and simulate it, then it looks perfect though. Is this a bug or a feature? Xcode is the IDE and storyboard is part of the IDE.

Comment: Is your question "Why does the storyboard representation of my WKWebView look different to what runs on the simulator?" If so, that's because setting constraints in the storyboard does not, by default, change how you have manually set the height and width in the storyboard. Constraints only apply at runtime, which then override whatever size you have set in the storyboard.

Comment: @AppDevGuy, ok I see, so my constraints are just fine, but it looks weird in the storyboard. Thank you for clearing this up. You can post it as an answer if you like, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments - Is your question "Why does the storyboard representation of my WKWebView look different to what runs on the simulator?" If so, that's because setting constraints in the storyboard does not, by default, change how you have manually set the height and width in the storyboard. Constraints only apply at runtime, which then override whatever size you have set in the storyboard.